# ** No sls-discount record is available. (91)

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

/*
sls-discount i sthe database name
*/Good day. I have another problem in regards again to value change of a specific browse.

my code for Add Button:

```
FIND CURRENT {&FIRST-TABLE-IN-QUERY-DIALOG-FRAME} NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
IF AVAIL {&FIRST-TABLE-IN-QUERY-DIALOG-FRAME} THEN DO:
    ASSIGN mode = 3.
    ASSIGN BROWSE BROWSE-13:READ-ONLY = NO
        sls-discount.dsc-amount:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO
        sls-discount.dsc-discount:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO
        sls-discount.log:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO.

    {&OPEN-QUERY-BROWSE-13}
    IF BROWSE-13:num-iterations ne 0 then
    BROWSE BROWSE-13:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW().
    BROWSE BROWSE-13:INSERT-ROW("BEFORE"). /*will cause value-change in browse*/
    APPLY 'entry' TO sls-discount.dsc-discount IN BROWSE BROWSE-13.

    RUN disp-enable.
END.
```

my code for browse-13:

```
ASSIGN xpromo-no = {&FIRST-TABLE-IN-QUERY-BROWSE-13}.promo-no
    mdlrid = {&FIRST-TABLE-IN-QUERY-BROWSE-13}.record-id.

MESSAGE xpromo-no mdlrid VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO.

OPEN QUERY BROWSE-16 FOR EACH sls.sls-disccount-model WHERE sls.sls-disccount-model.promo-no = xpromo-no
    AND sls.sls-disccount-model.record-id = mdlrid NO-LOCK,
    EACH sls.sls-model WHERE sls.sls-model.car-model = sls.sls-disccount-model.car-model NO-LOCK.
```

if I uncomment the entire value-change in a browse, it will display the message "** No DBName record is available. (91)" when clicking the add button. but if commented/removed, it will not display the message.

hope you can help me again .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've doubtless run into the infamous "partial field auto-completion" feature / bug. What that means is - if you cite a variable with no local definition for it, the Progress compiler will search all the available tables for a field that *starts* with the same sequence of letters and use that instead.

What the error is telling you is that the compiler associated a field with something in the "DBName" table, and when the code tries to access that variable, the DBName buffer isn't in scope - which is understandable since accessing it  wasn't your intention.

My guess is that you've mis-specified a BROWSE construct. Looking at your first set of constructs, you've got two different forms:

```
BROWSE BROWSE-13:READ-ONLY = NO
sls-discount.dsc-amount:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO
```

I'll bet one of these is wrong, and the compiler is associating the illegal "browse" citation with a field in DBName that starts with "Browse".

If you compile the code to an XREF file, it'll tell you which variable it's trying to associate with the DBName table. Correct that, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: In your comment, the problem was at "BROWSE BROWSE 13:.... etc". I tried to comment the whole 

`ASSIGN BROWSE BROWSE-13:READ-ONLY = NO
    sls-discount.dsc-amount:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO
    sls-discount.dsc-discount:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO
    sls-discount.log:READ-ONLY IN BROWSE BROWSE-13 = NO.`

still did not work... sorry if my comment arrangement is somewhat confusing.. cant set code to arrange like code in comments

Comment: In that case, compile the program to an XREF file (see the COMPILE doc references for specifics) and see what field it's associating with the DBName table.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what the problem on the code.. on click of Add button, the row inside browse-13 was arrange because of the `{&OPEN-QUERY-BROWSE-13}`. after that, because of `BROWSE BROWSE-13:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW()`, it focused on the TOP date on browse and last, `BROWSE BROWSE-13:INSERT-ROW("BEFORE")`, created a blank data row at the very top. thus triggering value-changed of browse-13. on my value-changed on browse-13, the beginning of the code was to `get current browse-13`. since it was focused on the blank row, it resulted in an error with no query being found. sorry if i did not include the syntax `get current` in my first example.